# Record selectors copy paste columns out of order issues

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform with record selectors enabled so people can copy/paste data.

The problem is the subform has column ordered for example as so :

```
A B C D E F
```

but when I copy and paste into Excel, I get as example.

```
A C E B D F
```

The date still copies correctly but how do I make the columns come out in the same order as they are in Access

Answer (score 0):

The column order isn't taken from the physical layout of the form, but from the tab order.

In design view of the subform, set the correct tab order of the details section.